# Earth Engine cast a string to a number for date filtering

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection with the year of the campaign as a string `"09/10"`.
To search through the require images I need to filter by dates turning the campaign into a year.

However I keep getting a message that complains I'm trying to do number operations on a string.

```
Number.int, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected: Number. Actual: String.
```

The following script is heavily inspired by one of the answers given by Rodrigo E. Principe.

```
var mapfunc = function(feat) {

   // get the geometry of the individual feature
   var geom = feat.geometry();


   var myCampaign = ee.String(feat.get(campaign));

   var myYear = myCampaign.slice(0,2);
   // take the campaign of the feature and iterate through the correct
   // set of images 
   var yearToIterate = ee.Number(myYear).toInt().add(2000);
   var subsetQKM = qKM
   .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(yearToIterate,10,1), 
   ee.Date.fromYMD(yearToIterate.add(1),5,25));



   // function to extract the value of the pixel for a feature
   var addProp = function(img, f) {

      var newf = ee.Feature(f);
      var date = img.date().format("Y-D");
      var b1 = ee.Number(img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 250).get('sur_refl_b01'));
      var b2 = ee.Number(img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 250).get('sur_refl_b02'));
      // Calculate the WDRVI the hard way
      var wdrviCoeff = ee.Number(0.2);
      var wDRVI = b2.multiply(wdrviCoeff).subtract(b1)
           .divide(b2.multiply(wdrviCoeff).add(b1));



      var wdrviDate = ee.String("wdrvi_").cat(date);
      //var b2Date = ee.String("sur_refl_b02_").cat(date);
      return ee.Feature(newf.set(wdrviDate, ee.Number(wDRVI)));
   }
   var newfeat = ee.Feature(subsetQKM.iterate(addProp, feat));
   return newfeat;
};


// add the data about the 
var newft = ft.map(mapfunc);
```

Comment: try `var myYear = ee.Number.parse(myCampaign.slice(0,2));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a `ee.String` to a `ee.Number` there is a special function:

```
var myYear = ee.Number.parse(myCampaign.slice(0,2));
```

It should work as expected.